# @Valid Springboot not sending message to postman response

Tags: java, spring-boot

i'm trying to use **javax.validation** on my Springboot project and the validations are not going to my postman response.

- My Model:

```java
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "nome")
private String nome;
```

- My Controller on the POST requisition:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/templates", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiModelProperty("Cria um novo template")
public ResponseEntity<TemplateDTO> cadastraTemplate(@RequestBody @Valid TemplateDTO templateDTO, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder) {
        Template template = Template.desconvertId(templateDTO);
        templateRepository.save(template);
        URI uri = uriComponentsBuilder.path("template/{id}").buildAndExpand(template.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(new TemplateDTO(template));
    }
```

- The **@Valid** is working, but is sending the message to my console, not when i send him on postman:
- The Console message:

```
2022-08-24 15:44:13.285 ERROR 1668 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.ages.joinfut.Model.Template] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='não deve estar vazio', propertyPath=nome, rootBeanClass=class com.ages.joinfut.Model.Template, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
]] with root cause
```

- On my Postman response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-08-24T18:44:13.302+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/example/templates"
}
```

Validation is working but why isn't going to response body on postman?

Comment: is your controller decorated with `@Validated` annotation? P.S. I'm not suggesting it, just asking

Comment: yes, above the @RestController:

Comment: `@Validated` `@RestController` `@RequestMapping(value = "/example")`

Comment: if you remove it your code will respond with 400 BAD REQUEST, which is better for invalid client input

Comment: i take it off, but keeps sending the 500 Internal Server Error to postman

Comment: Judging by the error validation, error is raised not on controller level, but on persistence level - `Template` class is a culprit, not `TemplateDTO`. If the validation would have failed on controller level, you would get the 400 response (if @Validated not present on class level as I said before). Anyway, you can create handlers for `MethodArgumentNotValidException` (for controller level validation failure) and `ConstraintViolationException` (for other level failure) and create custom response when validation failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an exception is thrown, Spring has to determine how to convert a Java exception to an Http response. This is done by the  `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. Your default `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` is catching the `ConstraintViolationException` and converting it to a 500 and eating the exception message. [Here's a guide](https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api) on setting up custom exception handlers so you can populate the response message with relevant info.